# Value [object%20Object] is added to request instead of a request parameter

Tags: node.js, express, request

Getting this error because [object%20Object] is added to url request instead of the parameter I'm passing to it: "http://localhost:3000/api/cookies/**[object%20Object]**"

On server side I have this:

```
router.get('/cookies/:URL', (req, res) => {
    request.get(req.params.URL, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(501).json(err);
        } else {
            const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
            if (cookies) {
              return res.status(200).json(cookies);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On client side:
cookiesservice.ts:

```
 getCookies(URL) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.serverAPI}/cookies/` + URL).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

cookies.component.ts:

```
searchCookies(URL) {
    this.cookieService.getCookies(URL).subscribe();
  }
```

cookies.component.html:

```
<form id="formData" #cookieData="ngForm">
      <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput placeholder="URL" name="URL" [(ngModel)]="cookieData.URL">
      </mat-input-container>
      <button mat-button type="button" id="searchCookies" (click)="searchCookies(cookieData.value)">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Any idea about the problem? Thanks!

Comment: console.log(URL) on your client side and see what it is ?

Comment: the error is stating you're returning a complex object instead of a value.  javascript cannot easily parse a complex object to string, but typically can other types.  I would log as @feiiiiii suggests, but my bet is that cookieData.value is a complex object.

Comment: The problem was that as URL I was receiving: { URL: "value"}, so I have to access to URL.URL. Thanks you so much for your help!